# MVP vs. Presentation Model, which one is better?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, mvp, presentation-model

**UPDATE**

MVP vs. Presentation Model, which one is better (for desktop application) - in terms of

1. maintainability
2. testability
3. complexity
4. flexibility
5. separation of concern - changing one
   component (view, controller, model
   etc) has minimal impact on the
   others.
6. performance (optional)
7. memory usage (optional)

Comment: What type of desktop applications?

Comment: Is this a windows framework comparison, so XAML/WPF versus MVC?

Comment: James, I've never use XAML before. You can find the explanation of MVP here http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you should stick with MVVM for WPF.  Here's an explanation of the models you could consider and the differences between them.

http://blogs.msdn.com/erwinvandervalk/archive/2009/08/14/the-difference-between-model-view-viewmodel-and-other-separated-presentation-patterns.aspx